# How to use bootstrap placeholder using EditorForModel construct in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, html.beginform

I'm creating a login page in ASP.NET MVC and using `bootstrap`.
I would like to place "username" and "password" inside of the corresponding `textboxes`.

I have the following code on the page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
   @Html.EditorForModel()
  <p><input type="submit" class="k-primary" value="Log In" /> </p>
}
```

Before changing to the above, the code used to be as follows:

```
<input id="UserName" type="text" class="k-textbox" placeholder="username" />
<br />
<input id="Password" type="password" class="k-textbox" placholder="password" />
<br />
<br />
<button id="Login" class="k-primary">Login</button>
```

That allowed to use a `placeholder` attribute.

Is that possible to do that using my `EditForModel` approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to achieve your goal, one of which is with custom Editor Templates... you can build one for a specific type, add annotation on models property to define the template ([UIHintAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)) and more see:

- [Brad Wilson - ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates, Part 1: Introduction](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html)
- [What are Display and Editor Templates? - ASP.NET MVC Demystified](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-display-and-editor-templates/)